# how do i correctly import a package in python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, module, package

[image: error importing package in vscode]

Hello everyone im currently learning python and i im having some problems importing modules and packages. Actually i think is more of a problem with vscode.

i have this package called "paquete" with a module (funciones) that i want to import to my "main" with some fuctions in it to test if it all works correctly but i still getting "emphasized items and unresolved-import" warnings.

but for some reason it works just fine.

is more of a annoying thing.

EDIT:

[image]
module with the function "funcion"

[image]

the warning that appears in the main folder "prueba" is "emphasized items"
i tried what u guys told me to do but it stills shows the warnings

Comment: Have a look at this post for standard practices when it comes to importing: https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/. Also, could you post the exact errors/warnings that come up?

Answer (score 1):

As you are trying to import a **specific function** from module in python 
You should use in this manner:

```
from paquete import funciones
```

If you want to import **full module** then use:

```
import paquete
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell whats in the funciones file. But normally this yellow import lines are telling you that you import functions, which you dont use.

Try this instead if you only want

> funcion

to be imported.

```
from paquete.funcions import funcion
```

This is also better because you import only the functions you need, not all of the functions you declared in the other file. Also all imports of the other file will be loaded into your file if you import with an asterix.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are doing all of this from within a directory named `prueba`. If you changed the import to `from prueba.paquete.funciones import *` it should work after you add a `__init__.py` file to your `prueba` directory. The other option is to use a relative import: `from .paquete.funciones import *`.

But do note that using `import *` is **strongly** discouraged when you are not working within the REPL. It's much better to import to the module and then reference things off the module, e.g. `from prueba.paquete import funciones`, `from .paquete import funciones`, or `import prueba.paquete.funciones`. That way you know exactly where things in your code came from without having to read the top of your file.

Answer (score -3):

pip3 intall "name"

Use Pycharm, rather than Vscode